# Displaying returned JSON

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display JSON in a dialogue box.Can't figure out a way to remove the brackets displayed.
Any help will be great.

[image]

This is JSON:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "comment": {
        "email_id": [
            "Email ID \"pixaflip.tech@gmail.com\" has already been taken."
        ],
        
    }
}
```

This is code i implemented to extract the JSON in Networkutils class:

```
Future<User> createUser(String url,{Map body}) async{
    return http.post(url,
          body:body).then((http.Response response){
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    
    var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    if(status == "false"){
       Map comment = extractdata["comment"];
    }
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    });
          
  }
```

This is how i displayed the message:

```
Networkutils _networkUtils = new NetworkUtils.
var list = _networkUtils.comment.values.toList();
_showDialogue("Registration", "$list");
```

Comment: you can use the json.decode() to convert into a Map right?, and print the key values as you wish!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this..

```
_showDialogue("Registration", "${list[0][0]}");
```

The reason for the 2 pairs of square brackets is that `_networkUtils.comment.values.toList()` is giving you a list of lists. So when you display it directly as a String, it shows up with the 2 pairs of brackets which indicates that it is a list of lists. So when we do `list[0][0]` it extracts out the first item of the first list inside `list`, which is what you want to display.